# Scheme: Passing defines inside macro definition to submacro?

Tags: macros, scheme, r7rs, chibi-scheme

Consider the following macro definition in R7RS scheme:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ bar)
      (begin
        (define baz 42)
        (define-syntax bar
          (syntax-rules ()
            ((_) baz)))))))
```

I have loaded this file into the repl of `chibi-scheme` and entered:

> > (foo bar)
>
> > (bar)

Instead of the expected output `42`, I got:

> ERROR: undefined variable: baz

Why is this so and how can I pass the defined value of `baz` in the outer macro to the inner macro?

Comment: Works fine in Racket.

Comment: In which compatibility mode?

Comment: I tried both `#!r6rs` and `#lang racket`.

Comment: Posted on the chibi-scheme mailing list to see whether chibi-scheme is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in chibi-scheme.  A macro definition needs to capture its environment; for `bar` the environment consists of `bar` itself and `baz`.  Then when you expand `bar` in another environment, the macro expansion needs to recognize that `baz` is bound in the env-of-definition.  chibi-scheme apparently doesn't recognize that `baz` is actually defined.

Additionally, another related problem, which you haven't seen in your post, is that even if the expansion of `bar` recognizes `baz` as bound, the loading/running of the code needs to find the value of `baz`.

Here is R6RS Ikarus Scheme:

```
> (define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ bar)
      (begin
        (define baz 42)
        (define-syntax bar
          (syntax-rules ()
            ((_) baz)))))))
> (foo bar)
> (bar)
42
>
```

Comment: That it is an error in chibi-scheme has been acknowledged by its author. The bug is already fixed! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chibi-scheme/Odz2D7exFP8

Answer (score 1):

I've run this on all the Schemes in [my test suite](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/wiki/ImplementationContrasts) that support syntax-rules, and it fails only on Chibi and MIT.  I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work, but I confess that macrology is still something of a black art to me.  In particular, it works in Foment, which is an R7RS system.  I haven't been able to build Sagittarius, so I can't test it there.